# message: "No PDF generation tool found! Please dowload a supported PHP PDF generation tool ... "

Tags: 7, files

I installed print module but I got this message when I wanted to install PDF section, I was reviewing pdf modules such as 
dompdf
mPDF 
TCPDF
wkhtmltopdf

but any works when I want to install them, please help

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that none work? I know that wkhtmltopdf requires (or used to) an X server. Most people, and what I did at a point, was to install Xvfb, https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml